# Update subquery psql

Tags: sql, postgresql

So i wanted to change the "category_code" of one of my tables to match the "category_code" of the other table.
This is the code that i thought of

```
UPDATE ventas.tb_subcategory
SET category_code = (SELECT tb_category.category_code
                        FROM ventas.tb_category
                        WHERE tb_subcategory.category_code = tb_category.category_code
                            AND category_name = 'A')
WHERE subcategory_name = 'C'
RETURNING tb_subcategory.category_code;
```

My data output is NULL and i dont really get why, some help please? :)
Take note that category_code was NULL before any change.
Thanks!

Comment: `"My data output is NULL"` and `"Take note that category_code was NULL before any change"` => How does **`WHERE  tb_subcategory.category_code = tb_category.category_code`** is supposed to correlate/join anything?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have one condition in your where clause that will not join any data from two tables because the value is null.

Maybe something like this would help you...

```
UPDATE tb_subcategory ts
SET category_code = t.category_code
   FROM tb_category t
   WHERE coalesce(ts.category_code,t.category_code)  = t.category_code
   AND t.category_name = 'A'
   AND ts.subcategory_name = 'C'
RETURNING ts.category_code;
```

Here is a demo:

> [DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=9725285d134198281a8f9c5d4b85301c)

Comment: Thanks!!! It worked perfectly, looks like the coalesce command was the right answer!

Comment: Happy to help. Please do be aware of this situations: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=fc7ca1d06819dbab2020c96a1ac0c93c

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm . . . how about this?

```
UPDATE ventas.tb_subcategory sc
    SET category_code = c.category_code
    FROM ventas.tb_category c
    WHERE sc.category_code = c.category_code AND
          sc.subcategory_name = 'C' AND
          c.category_name = 'A'
    RETURNING c.category_code;
```

This only assigns values where there is a match.